# webpack watch compiler - get file that caused recompilation

Tags: node.js, webpack

Does webpack.compiler have a property that informs you which file caused recompilation? (on watch of course)

This is what I have so far, could not find in `stats` variable this file, however:

```
webpack.compiler.plugin('done', (stats) => {
      console.log(stats);
});
```

however, reading console I cannot find my file that caused recompilation. Is there such a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

You can get file on `invalid` compiler event

sample code to print file name and timestamp:

```
compiler.plugin('invalid', (fileName, changeTime)=> {
  console.log("FileName: " + fileName);
  console.log("ChangeTime:" + changeTime);
});
```